# virtualbox перестала стартовать машина после

Tags: debian, память, virtualbox

перестала загружаться гостевая  debian после того как закончилась память hdd.
памяти было у виртуальной машины 20гб, начал закачивать большой файл, память закончилась файл не докачался, виртулку выключил, далее увеличил память виртуального носителя, далее включил виртуалку но она не стартует, просто моргает значек нижнего подчеркивания
как запустить?

Comment: Загрузиться с диска (iso-образа), удалить файл и увеличить раздел. Ну и попутно в логах почитать, почему не стартует